# How can i display a JIRA wallboard in a html website?

Tags: html, jira

if i just copy the jira wallboard url and paste it into an iframe the content is obviously not displayed because you need login permission to see the Jira wallboard.

How can i display urls which are cross browser protected by a login?

I came across the OpenID authentication but i just dont understand a word.

Regards

151

Comment: [Let me Google that for you](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/8630585/how-do-i-embed-an-agile-board-on-an-external-page). Also, this question will probably be closed, it's too broad and lacking in detail.

Comment: hi rac. thank you very much and sorry for the banal question but i have no clue about jira and this stuff but i need to work with it since today...

Comment: I have the same issue, I need to get the wallboard/dashboard shown on an internal webpage, as we have our own status screen service running, and just want to add some of the Jira screens, without having to create the charts our-self.

Answer (score 1):

You can open up the System Dashboard to anonymous users (people not logged in) to bypass the requirement to login: edit the "Browse Projects" permission to include the group "Anyone" (Issues -> Permission Schemes) and edit the Permission Scheme of the projects whose content is included in the System Dashboard. You can edit the System Dashboard itself in System -> System Dashboard (under heading User Interface).

Unfortunately at the moment it seems there's some problems with viewing wallboards or dashboards in Jira 7, but you can see if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you for the approach! Unfortunately this didnt work for me...there was a plugin which is not supportet in Jira 7 any longer. 
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jirawallboard.atlassian-wallboard-plugin/cloud/overview